# Switching elements in a list (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a program that takes in a list of strings. The strings contains of spacing and `n chars`, either `'*'`, `'#'`, or `'|'`, depending on the lists. So, given two lists, e.g..

```
["     #     ","    # #   " ,"   # # #  " ,"  # # # # " ," # # # # #" ] 
["     |     ","     |     ","     |     ","     |     ", "     |    "]
```

My `switch` method would find the first string which contains `'#'` in the first list, and put it in front of the other `'#'`-containing strings in the other list. And if there were none, then we put the `'#'`-containing string behind all the `'|'` strings in the list.

In other words this models the Towers of Hanoi move from one pole to another where `'|'` shows an empty pole and `'#'` stands for a disk.

Thus the goal here is to move the top-most disk from the first pole onto the top-most disk on the other pole, if any; or otherwise put the moved disk on the bottom.

My code:

```
-- Switches elements from two lists, returns a list with the two new lists inside
switch :: [String] -> [String] -> [[String]]
switch [] [] = []
switch xs ys =
  let
    e1 = fromJust (findStr '#' xs)            -- Find the first string in list that contains '#'
    e2 = fromJust (findStr '|' $ reverse ys)  -- Find the first string in the reversed list that contains '|' 
    newX = e2 : tail xs                       -- New list with its head replaced by e2
    newY = tail ys : [[e1]]                   -- New list with its last string which contains '|' replaced by e1
    in
      newX : newY 

--Finds and returns the string to be switched
findStr :: Char -> [String] -> Maybe String
findStr c xs = listToMaybe [s | s <- xs, c `elem` s]
```

When I run it, I get this actual output:

```
switch ["     #    " ,"    # #   " ,"   # # #  " ,"  # # # # " ," # # # # #"] 
       ["     |     ","     |     ","     |     ","     |     ","     |     "]

ghci> [["     |     ","    # #   " ,"   # # #  " ,"  # # # # " ," # # # # #"],
       ["     |     ","     |     ","     |     ","     |     "],
       ["     #    "]]
```

Desired output:

```
switch ["     |     ","    # #   " ,"   # # #  " ,"  # # # # " ," # # # # #"] 
       ["     |     ","     |     ","     |     ","     |     ","     #    "]

ghci> [["     |     ","     |    " ,"   # # #  " ,"  # # # # "   ," # # # # #"],
       ["     |     ","     |     ","     |     ","     # #     ","     #    "]]
```

If I try to write it like this:

```
newY = tail ys : e1  -- New list with its last string which contains '|' replaced by e1
```

(Removed the brackets surrounding `e1`)I get an error saying:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[String]’
  Expected: [[String]]
    Actual: String
```

What am I doing wrong here? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Reading this is pretty difficult. Perhaps it would be easier if you split up your lists over muiltiple lines, with one item per line

Comment: Why don't you give us minimum examples?

Comment: I am trying to create a the game Tower of Hanoi, and I am using the lists of strings as 'pieces'. Im not sure what you mean by minimum examples, but I know that the lists always contains strings, and they have the same number of string-elements.

Comment: a list with 4 elements is smaller than a list with five. and a list with 3 elements is yet smaller. so if your problem can  be equally demonstrated with 3 or 4 strings, using 3 would be better, more minimal example. using 2 or even 1 would be even better, so it is easier to follow and understand. right now I don't understand what you are asking. if you'd give some _minimal_ sample input, and its desired and actual output, that would help.

Comment: I just want to put the string inside the inner list instead of it being in a separate inner list.

Comment: @Mampenda, if I had an issue in drawing the grid of a chessboard, I would write an example with a 2x2 board, rather than a true 8x8 chessboard. That's what somebody is suggesting that you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of your issues with the specific code you posted, a *simple* way to solve your problem is to use `span` (or `break`), then combine the two resulting tuples' components with `++`:

```
move :: [String] -> [String] -> Maybe ([String], [String])
move xs ys 
   | ( (a,h:b) , (c,d) ) <- (break (elem '#') xs,
                             break (elem '#') ys)
       = Just (a ++ b, c ++ [h] ++ d)
   | otherwise
       = Nothing
```

So that now we have,

```
> move [" # "," # # "," # # # "] [" | "," | "," | "]
Just ([" # # "," # # # "],[" | "," | "," | "," # "])

> move [" | "," # "," # # # "] [" | "," | "," | "," # # "]
Just ([" | "," # # # "],[" | "," | "," | "," # "," # # "])

> move [" | "," | "," | "] [" # "," # # "," # # # "]
Nothing
```

This code uses *pattern guards*.

I've also changed the output type.

Answer (score -1):

This code solves the issue I had:

```
-- Switches elements from two lists, returns a list with the two new lists inside
switch :: [String] -> [String] -> [[String]]
switch [] [] = []
switch xs ys =
  let
    rs = reverse ys
    (e1, n1) = findStr '#' xs                                -- Find the first string in list that contains '#'
    (e2, n2) = findStr '|' rs                                -- Find the first string in the reversed list that contains '|' 
    newX = e2 : (take (n1-1) xs ++ drop n1 xs)               -- New list with its head replaced by e2
    newY = [reverse (take (n2-1) rs ++ [e1] ++ drop n2 rs)]  -- New list with its last string which contains '|' replaced by e1
    in
      newX : newY

--Finds and returns the string to be switched
findStr :: Char -> [String] -> (String, Int)
findStr c xs = head [s | s <- zip xs [1..], c `elem` fst s]
```